# C# WPF prevent binding back to listview

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a `Listview` in my WPF windows and there I have a binding to a property `List<User> users;`
I also have a edit/add form beside the listview where I want to edit the user and click on the save button to save the user. I have the bindingContext of the groupbox of the form set to currentUser which is set on OnSelectionChange event of the ListView. Everything(bindings) work fine but my problem is:

When I change the text of the textbox which are bound to currentUser and leave the textbox, it is automatically updated in the listView. I first want to click on 'Save User' before the ListView is updated. How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Code example, please.

Comment: if they both are bound to same object this is normal behaviour

Comment: @Muds, thats what im trying to prevent.

Comment: then its going to be dirty, v dirty..

Comment: try playing around with on property changed.. and update source triggers

Comment: if you get cant get solution, post your code , will try to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option1:

You could set [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.100).aspx) of your `textbox` (on your update form) to [`Explicte`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.100).aspx),
and only call [`UpdateSource` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource(v=vs.100).aspx), when clicking `Save`.

Option2:

You could also set `Listview`'s each column's [`BindingMode` to `OneTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx), and update/refresh it's `DataContext` after `Save`. (ie. by setting View's DataContext to null and then set it back.)

Comment: It helped me somehow but not fully. What I want is , is to be automated. Doing the way you mentioned, Im preventing my textbox to bind back to source, but what I actually want is actually prevent the item in listview to get updated. 

Doing the way you described, I have to do updatesource for all other textboxes.

Comment: @DesterDezzods, see option 2.

Comment: option 2 isn't helping. ' ItemsSource="{Binding users, Mode=OneTime}" ' this does updates the listitems immediately

Comment: @DesterDezzods, please try set each columns' binding mode to Onetime, not the ItemsSource of the whole ListView. This will make your Listview show the initial value until you explicitly refresh/change it's DataContext.  However, I do think Option1 sounds more common and makes more sense.